# Link to Google Play app from Phonegap : Protocol not supported

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I am trying to open directly a Google Play application details page from a Phonegap app. 
I have added this line in my html page:

```
<a href="market://details?id=com.publishername.myapp">Link to market</a>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
The protocol isn't supported. (market://details?id=com.publishername.myapp).
```

I have tried to find a solution on Google without success.

Comment: ??? `http://` is not good enough?

Comment: @shoe rat I would like to open the Google Play app instead of the web browser. Http opens only the web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported the issue in the cordova bug tracker.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3902

The development team has just made a commit to fix the issue. It should be fixed in Cordova 2.9.

Comment: The fix in the Cordova bug tracker is ridiculous as they have hardcoded market:// as supported URL. What about custom URLs triggered by WebIntent Cordova plugin .. e.g. myapp://

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with Phonegap, but if I need to launch Play Store from an HTML page here is how I'd do:

**Java**

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {
    // lots of lines of code

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "PlayStore");

    // moar code

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void launch() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.publishername.myapp"));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    // and many moar
}
```

**HTML/Javascript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function launchPlayStore() {
            PlayStore.launch();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- lots of lines of html -->

    <a href="javascript:launchPlayStore();">Link to market</a>

    <!-- moar html -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the hard way :). I am pretty sure that the simple link was working with previous phonegap versions.